# How to turn off “child.logfile=sys.stdout” in pexpect?

Tags: python, pexpect

I’m new on Python. Recently I wrote an script to ssh to server by using “pexpect”
To show the login process, I redirect the logfile to stdout. 
At the end of script, it will hand over the control to user. 
When I type on command prompt, all keys I typed became double. 
I think this is due to sending log file to stdout.
How do I turn it off? 
I tried many suggestion from the web, but none does help.
Please help. 
Thanks a lot, 
Sheng

Below is my script:

```
def login_with_ip_on_the_list():
    global user_input_argv2
    child=pexpect.spawn('ssh xxx@xx.xx.xx.xx’)
   #child.logfile=sys.stdout #display progress on screen
    child.expect(['password','Password'])
    child.sendline(‘xxxxx’)
    child.expect(‘xxx)
    child.sendline('\r')
    child.expect(‘xxx’)
    child.sendline('\r')
    child.interact()
```

Comment: `child.logfile = None`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Thomas, here below is how I implemented it, it works for me.               
    f=open(os.devnull,'w')   
    sys.stdout=f             
    child.logfile=sys.stdout 
    child.interact()

Comment: `child.setecho(False)`